# Tool to detect non-dotted relative imports in Python?

Tags: python, import, relative-path

It's considered bad Python to use imports like this:

```
import my_module
```

When you are doing a relative import and this would work:

```
from . import my_module
```

Is there a tool that can detect these non-dotted relative imports in my code and warn me so I could update them to the dotted syntax? [My project](http://garlicsim.org) has hundreds of Python modules and I would like to do this automatically. (Possibly such a tool would override `__import__` and detect the bad imports as they happen when I run the program.)

Does anyone know of such tool?

Comment: 2to3 will automatically convert them, because it's compulsory in Python 3--you might be able to repurpose the relevant code from that for static analysis.

Comment: The relevant code is here: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/lib2to3/fixes/fix_import.py?view=markup Alternatively, you could just run 2to3 with only that fixer: `2to3 -w -f import myproject/`

Comment: @Thomas K: It worked, feel free to post it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Reposted as an answer because it apparently did the trick]

2to3 will automatically convert them, because it's compulsory in Python 3.

Here's the [relevant source code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/lib2to3/fixes/fix_import.py?view=markup) if you want to modify it for your purposes.

Alternatively, you could just run 2to3 with only that fixer: `2to3 -w -f import myproject/`

Answer (score 1):

[pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) gives warnings about relative imports, along with tons of other stuff that's considered, for one reason or another, "bad Python".

Comment: Can it actually tell the difference between local modules and `site-packages` modules?

Comment: Yes; it's aware of sys.path and should issue the warnings only for actual relative imports.